# I need a help in date

Tags: python

How can I print date in Python? I need a code which subtract present date -1 and present date -2

For example, if the date was 29. So it would take give us 27 and 28 , because of presentdate-1 and presentdate-2

Same way I want in this scenario
Today I 1(day)
So I need presentdate -1 and presentdate -2 which will be 30 and 31.

```
today = datetime.now()
year = (today.strftime("%Y"))
month = (today.strftime("%m"))
today1 = (today.strftime("%d"))

data = datetime.datetime.now()
print(data)
```

```
def daterange(startdate , enddate):
         for n in range(int((enddate-startdate).days)):
                  yield startdate+timedelta(n)
enddate = date(int(year) , int(month),yesterday)
startdate = date(int(year),int(month),check)
```

What this do is, suppose if I give input as 25, it will print all the days till today. But as today is 1(day) I am getting it error

````
enddate = date(int(year) , int(month),yesterday)
ValueError: day is out of range for month```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.date` and `datetime.timedelta` for this:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, date
>>> d = date(2022, 1, 3)
>>> d - timedelta(days=2)
datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
```

Comment: I need only the day in a loop

Comment: Nope , see the question code  its different actually , i can only specify day , not month and year

Comment: Can you just use dummy values for year and month?

Comment: I only need day , not date. What i need this do is , suppose if i give input as 25 , it will print all the days till today But as today is 1(day) i am getting it error